# Why do companies need to file form 8A?

Tags: united-states, ipo, sec, electronic-filing

I currently follow a company (DTST) in progress to be listed on the Nasdaq Capital Market (previously traded on the OTC).

After filling the [S1 report with multiple amendments](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/0001419951/000173112221000763/e2720_s1a.htm), they also recently filed [an 8A form (or 8A-12b).](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/0001419951/000173112221000796/e2729_8a12b.htm)
To learn about the IPO process, I tried to compare the SEC fillings of DTST to other companies recently listed on the Nasdaq Capital Market.

My question is:
I see other companies that got listed without filling the 8A or 8A-12B form, so why it is needed? I don't grasp how it is useful.

*NOTE: I am not affiliated with the company mentioned, but I have invested in it.

Comment: Do the other listed companies file a Form 10 instead of Form 8A? https://www.securitieslawyer101.com/2015/form-10-vs-8-a-registration-statements/

Comment: Your question starts as though you have no connection with the company ("_I currently follow a company_" and "_they also recently filed_") but ends "_so why do **we** need that?_", which suggests you might be part of, or have a connection with, DTST. If this is simply a typo, you should probably [edit] the question to fix it. If you _are_ affiliated, you should probably say so explicitly (but would probably make it off-topic, as it wouldn't really then be about _Personal_ Finance & Money).

Comment: @TripleHound I edited the question. I am not affiliated with the mentioned company.